# Adobe digital edition

Tags: drm

I want to create website for ebook vendor sell own ebook, And i looking for method for protect ebook, and i found adobe digital edition which can solve this because reader have to identify device with adobe, so i spend more time on the internet for find how to convert pdf or image for adobe digital edition. Unfortunately i cannot find it. Please help me solve that. "Can i convert pdf or image for adobe digital edition with drm"

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you clarify a little bit what you are trying to do? What is your specific question? What file format do you want to start with, and what do you want to have at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, finally i'm found the answer. You can use adobe content server service for store your ebook when you upload to the server you will get ascm file for download the ebook and the ascm file can open on Adobe digital edition which the reader can download adobe digital edition in free program and reader have to identified device with adobe, so you can limit your ebook for use in personal cannot pass them to another.